# Static method sorting in ascending alphabetical order

Tags: java

I am curious to know, I have a problem which is asking me the following two things.

1. Modify the class WordList to include a method called sortAlpha() that sorts the
   list into ascending Alphabetical (dictionary) order. Hint: make use of the static
   method sort(…) of the class Collections.
2. Modify the main method in the class Words so that after the list is printed, it is
   sorted (by making use of the new method) and then printed out again.

My question is this. How can i go around sorting a word list in alphabetical order and modify main method in the class words so that after list prints, its sorted and printed again??

Here is the code for the following two classes. The main class code is here and this is called Words.java which i have done fine:

```
    import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
    public class Words {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            WordList ws = new WordList();
            String in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    "Click cancel to end or enter a word and click OK");
            while (in != null) {
                ws.addWord(in);
                in = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        "Click cancel to end or enter a word and click OK");
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Word list = " + ws.toString());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "First word = " + ws.getFirst());
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Last word = " + ws.getLast());
        }
    }
```

Here is the other class which is not the main but is connected to the main class called WordList.java:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    public class WordList {
        private ArrayList<String> theWordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        public void addWord(String s) {
            theWordList.add(s);
        }

    public String getFirst() {
    if (theWordList.isEmpty ())
                return "-";
                return theWordList.get (0);

        }
    public String getLast() {
     if (theWordList.isEmpty ())
                return "-";
            return theWordList.get (theWordList.size () -1);
        }
        public String toString() {
            return theWordList.toString();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Collections.sort(theWordList)` to sort the List. Since the List contains Strings, you don't have to implement the `Comparable` interface or things like that yourself.

Just create a new method in the `WordList` class that sorts the List and call this method whenever you want the List to get sorted.

EDIT: Click [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator)) to get to the Java API for the `Collections` class.